# Managing tasks per week

Tags: ms-project, project-management-style

I would like to create a weekly deployment schedule for components, which would then be illustrated on a GANT diagram.

I would like to create a schedule for the deployment of components by week, which will be shown on a GANT chart. MS Project now allows you to enter a start date and an end date, instead of entering dates, I would like to enter week numbers and at the same time be able to display it on Gant.

For example :

> Task A: Start week W4 - End week W6
>
> Task B: Start week W12 - End week W13

Is this possible and if so how can I proceed?

[image]

As you can see in the picture, on the right, the gant is well displayed.
However on the left side, the purpose is to enter a number of week as a start date, and as you can see I need to select a specific date rather than a number of week.

Thank you

Comment: Are you comfortable with coding in VBA? That's likely the only way to build what you need.

Comment: I m not comfortable with VBA, do you know where I can find some macro VBA to help me to do it ?

Comment: Actually, as Ashok has kindly shared with us in the "answer" below, you probably *don't* have to use VBA to get this particular job done.  However – Kikou, "definitely set aside some time to cursorily familiarize yourself with VBA."  There's tons of material out there on the Internet *(of course),* and it's really not too hard to acquire enough of a working knowledge of it to be really helpful when you **do** need it. A very short(!) function is sometimes "just what the doctor ordered."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a thread in Microsoft Technet Forums for Project Standard and Professional General Questions and Answers](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/7a470604-21d2-4176-b13f-5941efd9ce86/add-column-with-start-date-in-week-format-12352?forum=projectprofessional2010general):

There are two suggestions:

1. In the options/general menu, select "W04-4" in the date format. Then the start and finish dates will be displayed with the week number and day of the week.
2. You could also create a custom field with a formula using the ProjDateConv function with the pjDate_Www_dd format option. Doing this, you'll keep the default start and finish date as is and just display week number in the calculated field. Exact formula below:

   ProjDateConv([Start];pjDate_Www_dd)